# How can I force a UICollectionView to scroll to a particular row AND load the cell for that row, while the collection view is hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a list of stuff, and a detail screen that comes in when the user taps an item, completely covering the collection view. This detail screen has a "Next" button that advances the detail view on to the next item in the list underneath, without ever exposing the list.

I am using `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` in order to move the "current" row of the collection view along; this works, except that it doesn't actually force the collection view to scroll to the new row until I remove the detail view from over top of it. As a result, the cells for the newly exposed row aren't loaded until after I remove the detail.

How can I get a UICollectionView to load a cell for a row if the collection view is not actually visible at the time (i.e. is hidden)?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue, and resolved it by setting the screen that covers the UICollectionView to have a background colour with a little bit of transparency.

```
detailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithred: 0.5 green: 0.5 blue: 0.5 alpha: 0.999]
```

With the covering view having a touch of transparency, `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` works fine.